# Error when running envoy task, server [ server_name] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, envoyproxy

I'm trying to use laravel envoy task runner to deploy an app with just a command, however when I execute envoy run deploy I het the following error message in terminal.

```
deployuser@gabriel-ubuntu-1:/var/www/dtcburger.es$ envoy run deploy

In TaskContainer.php line 193:

  Server [web] is not defined.


run [--continue] [--pretend] [--path PATH] [--conf CONF] [--] <task>

deployuser@gabriel-ubuntu-1:/var/www/dtcburger.es$
```

It can't find my server despite me adding the correct user and IP to @servers array...

This is part of my Envoy.blade.php file:

```
@servers(['web' => 'deployuser@206.189.6.76'])

@setup
    $on = 'web';
    $user = 'deployuser';
    $domain = 'gabrielgbtest.com';
    $repo = 'git@gitlab.com:GabotronES/projectname.git';
@endsetup


@story('deploy')
    clone
    dependencies
    migrations
    perms
    nginx
    ssl
@endstory


@task('pull', ['on' => $on, 'confirm' => true])
    git fetch origin master
    git reset --hard origin/master
@endtask
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It might be a little late to answer your question now, but it might help others who have similar problems.

Sometimes this error might be caused by the `servers([])` statement doesn't support writing in multi-lines.

Comment: You may have been late, but you were right.  Neither ChatGPT 3.5 and 4.0 could figure this one out.  So much hassle for such an easy fix: do *not* line break the @servers([])

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to include `pull` task in `@story('deploy')` section.

It would be something like:

```
@story('deploy')
    pull
    dependencies
    migrations
    perms
    nginx
    ssl
@endstory
```

I think, clone should be pull.

**Edited:**

Also define the other tasks in list like `dependancies`, `migratioms`, `perms`, `nginx` and `ssl` same as you defined `pull` else you should have to remove from list.

This may help you to define that.
https://github.com/papertank/envoy-deploy

Check the `Envoy.blade.php` tasks definition and calling from `@story('deploy')` section.

All the best!

Comment: Try remove other task from list.

Comment: @gabogabans hopefully solution works for you! let me know if still having issue.